# PostgreSQL question - finding sum of sales by state

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help writing the query, we have a table called SALES, which has 3 columns as below:

Column Names: sale_id, state, sale_amount_cents

I assume the sale_amount_cents has the sale amount in cents as opposed to dollars, and our end answer needs to be in dollars so we would have to multiply by 100.

Can someone please help writing the query to sum sales, in dollars, by date, rounding to two decimal places, and sorting from the greatest sale amount to the least?

I assume the query would look like this:

```
UPDATE SALES SET sale_amount_cents=sale_amount_cents*100
SELECT SUM(sale_amount_cents) from SALES
GROUP BY STATE
ORDER BY sale_amount_cents DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  state, SUM(sale_amount_cents)/100 as Sales_in_dollar from SALES 
GROUP BY STATE ORDER BY SUM(sale_amount_cents) DESC
```